# Should we have a 'Kundalini' Tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we have a 'Kundalini' Tag?

I have been studying Kundalini and using it throughout my meditation and life but have a lot of questions about the act which is equally physical and spiritual. I also would like to have more people learn about it as it has enhanced my life tremendously. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid your question was closed down - I believe this is a Hindu concept and as such the question belongs on our sister site [Hinduism SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/)

Hope you get the answer you are looking for over there.

Comment: Is kundalini really exclusively hindu? There seems to be buddhist advice to not get too attached to kundalini energy. Maybe kundalini should be considered to the same extent as hindu cosmology which is not dissimilar to buddhist cosmology.